# best way to read and modify files (c++)

Tags: c++

is it better to modify the file using positioning (seekg/seekp ) while it's in the hard drive
with out loading it to the RAM (into an object)

or read it as a whole into an object then treat the object (delete,modify,add...)

better "mostly speed"

Comment: When you ask about "better", are you referring to readability, maintainability, memory, speed or something else? There is rarely a generic "better" that covers all cases.

Comment: What fraction of the file will you modify?  Is that fraction going to change in its total size after modification, or just be modified in certain bytes with no shifting occurring afterward?

Comment: There is no generic answer. Tell us more about your project - is speed really your problem, and does it really have to do with accessing files? Why not make a sample implementation with either, and then compare your timings?

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on your usecase. For one thing there are cases where you can not fit the whole file in the RAM(if it is huge). Also if you only need to perform a small change, loading the whole file will be a huge overhead.

On the other hand if you need to read/modify a huge portion of the file multiple times and it is reasonably big, loading it into the RAM will make sense and will improve the performance.